# Rationale behind the C syntax for blocks

Tags: c, syntax, notation, curly-braces

I was recently trying to find the reasons that led to the use of curly braces for blocks (*compound-statements*) in the C language and other languages of the [same family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages).

Thinks like square brackets for arrays or parentheses to change operator precedence seems to come from the [mathematical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_notation#Expressions) used for these things so it makes sense to me. The semicolon makes sense too, it's meant to separate [related sentences with independent clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon), and it does something like that in C.

But I couldn't find something similar for curly braces: they are used for [sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) in mathematics, and something somehow similar is their use in [musical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_%28music%29#Ensemble_staves) (*Ensemble staves*) where they are used to *indicate that the music on all the staves is to be played simultaneously* (not quite the same use but I thought it was closer than their use in mathematics for sets).

Also, I was wondering if C is actually the first language to introduce this block syntax or did it just popularize it?

Comment: Could be as simple as `( )` and `[ ]` were already taken. Why do we use `< >` for templates / generics ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first [curly brace programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Curly-bracket_languages) was [BCPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCPL) in 1966, although it allowed `$(` and `$)` to delimit blocks in addition to `{` and `}`.

BCPL was based on [CPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPL_(programming_language)) which used the unusual (to modern programmers' eyes) `§` to open a block and the same symbol with a line through it to close the block. Martin Richards, the inventor of BCPL in ["How BCPL evolved from CPL":](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mr10/cpl2bcpl.pdf) says:

> CPL used a section symbol (`§`) to be equivalent to Algol’s `BEGIN` and a
>   section symbol overprinted with a slash to represent `END`. BCPL adopted
>   `$(` and `$)` for these tokens and as with CPL such section brackets could
>   be tagged, allowing a close section bracket to close multiple
>   sections. Unfortunately this convention lead to rather obscure
>   programming errors and so when curly brackets (`{` and `}`) became
>   available, they were only used as untagged section brackets and the
>   use of `$(` and `$)` was discouraged.

Curly braces came to C (1972) via [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)) (1969).

Comment: I think you are guessing right. The availability of special characters in character sets and on keyboards was (and still is sometimes) a problem for portable programming. This is why `{` and `}` still have alternative encodings as trigraph (`??<` and `??>`) and digraph (`<%` and `%>`).

Comment: My guess was wrong, so I edited it away -- I found a reference from Martin Richards and replaced my guess with that.

Comment: Thanks for the link to "[How BCPL evolved from CPL](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mr10/cpl2bcpl.pdf)", it's pretty interesting to have an explanation on the evolution from a syntax / language to another!